# /usr/lib/* files had been deleted, how to restore these files

Tags: linux, operating-system, centos, system, restore

I accidently deleted all files in /usr/lib/, how to resotre the files!!
My OS is centos 6.6.
several command cannot be used,such as:yum,rpm.
what should i do, my boss will kill me~~
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is off-topic here, but I sure hope you have a recent backup handy. Good luck.

Comment: If you have some backup then you are saved or you can try to copy from some other centos installation. But any custom command will not work either. All i can say is good luck to you on restoring those files.

Comment: It's time to say good bye! Wipe it out and re-install it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: remove the disk from the machine

Step 2: add the disk to another machine as a non-primary disk

Step 3: boot the other machine, and mount the non-primary disk and (if they are separate) its /usr and /usr/lib as `/mnt/usr/lib`

Step 4: recover from your most recent backup

Comment: could i restore the files by LiveCD?

Comment: I have no way to answer that.  I don't know what files used to be there, to tell you where to get them back from.  That's why you have backups.